# Manipulate Excel File inside Dynamics CRM

Tags: c#, excel, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm trying manipulate an excel file (xls), using a custom plugin created for me on Dynamics CRM 2015.
The file is inside a disk c:/ on my Dynamics CRM server. 
My issue is when i try open the excel file to insert data, i have the next error:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault,
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: 
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC):

My code is the next:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook oWB;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet oSheet;
                try
                {
                    selectedPath = @"...\newtest.xls";

                    Object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

                    oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

                    var myExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
                    {
                        Visible = false
                    };
                    oWB = myExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename: @"tst.xls", ReadOnly: false);

                    oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
                    oSheet.Cells[10, 4] = "DATA";
                    oWB.SaveCopyAs(selectedPath);
                    oWB.Close();
                    oXL.Quit();
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oXL);

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    throw new Exception(e.ToString());
                }
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: I would not recommend using the Office Interop libraries in a plugin, I've seen numerous issues pop-up over time when doing so. My recommendation is to look at one of the standalone .NET Excel libraries (Spreadsheet.Net, EPPlus, etc.)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Can you give me some real example of a free library?

Comment: Take a look at http://epplus.codeplex.com/. There is example source code available there.